# Thunderbolt ex4 and Docking Station

Tags: windows, usb, bios

Last year I Put myself a gaming PC together. As I am also working in Home Office with my company notebook, I wanted everything connected to a docking station, so I just need to switch the USB-C Cable between the two devices. I bought the Thunderboltex 4 from ASUS, connected it via display port with my graphics card, activated thunderbolt in die bios settings and everything worked like charm... Until recently. I added a new SSD Card to my gaming pc, turned it on, monitors came online... but nothing else.

It seems to my that suddenly the USB 2.0 connection from the thunderboltex4 and my mainboard stopped working and I can´t get it running again. I tried another USB 2.0 device with the same USB 2.0 headers and it works... so I thought: Maybe it is the cable, so I bought another USB 2.0 header cable... same result. The monitors are working, the peripherals not. No mouse, no keyboard, no LAN, no headphones.

Maybe someone on here got an idea what is wrong?